# How to Extract the Current Hour value for Integer arithmetic? (Python)

Tags: python, datetime, object

I tried to extract the hour value from the result of the code : `time.localtime(time.time())`, thinking its a string after printing its values. I now realize its an object. How then, can I get the value of the current hour from the object, as an integer to be able to arithmetic on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [consult the docs for `time`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/time.html#time.struct_time), or, if you're lazy like me, you could just take a look at `dir()` for your object and see what makes sense:

```
>>> import time
>>> x = time.localtime(time.time())
>>> dir(x) # output below formatted for readability and removing _-prefixed things
['count', 'index', 'n_fields', 'n_sequence_fields', 'n_unnamed_fields', 'tm_hour', 
 'tm_isdst', 'tm_mday', 'tm_min', 'tm_mon', 'tm_sec', 'tm_wday', 'tm_yday', 'tm_year']
>>> x.tm_hour
23
```

And, in fact, in my time zone as I write this answer, it is indeed 23:xy.